# Why Rust reset some variables after a loop?

Tags: testing, rust

I finished reading The Rust Programming Languange some time ago and I'm creating a simple http-server for the sake of teaching myself Rust.

In a function meant to parse a `&[u8]` and create a `HttpRequest` object, I noticed that a loop that should be parsing the headers is actually not updating some variables used to track the state of parsing:

```rust
pub fn parse_request(buffer: &[u8]) -> Result<HttpRequest, &'static str> {
    let (mut line, mut curr_req_reader_pos) = next_req_line(buffer, 0);

    let (method, path, version) = parse_method_path_and_version(&line)?;

    let (line, curr_req_reader_pos) = next_req_line(buffer, curr_req_reader_pos);
    //eprintln!("--- got next line: {}, {} ---", curr_req_reader_pos, String::from_utf8_lossy(line));
    let mut headers = vec![];
    let mut lel = 0;
    while line.len() > 0 {
        //eprintln!("LOOP");
        let header = parse_header(&line);
        eprintln!("--- parsed header: {} ---", String::from_utf8_lossy(line));
        headers.push(header);
        let (line, curr_req_reader_pos) = next_req_line(buffer, curr_req_reader_pos);
        //eprintln!("--- got next line: {}, {} ---", curr_req_reader_pos, String::from_utf8_lossy(line));
        let (line, curr_req_reader_pos) = next_req_line(buffer, curr_req_reader_pos);
        //eprintln!("--- got next line: {}, {} ---", curr_req_reader_pos, String::from_utf8_lossy(line));
        //eprintln!("LOOP");
        lel += 10;
        //break;
    }

    let (line, curr_req_reader_pos) = next_req_line(buffer, curr_req_reader_pos);
    //eprintln!("--- got next line: {}, {} ---", curr_req_reader_pos, String::from_utf8_lossy(line));
    //eprintln!("{}", lel);

    let has_body;
    match method.as_ref() {
        "POST" | "PUT" | "PATCH" => has_body = true,
        _ => has_body = true
    };

    let body;
    if has_body {
        let (line, curr_req_reader_pos) = next_req_line(buffer, curr_req_reader_pos);
        body = String::from_utf8_lossy(line).to_string();
    } else  {
        body = String::new();
    }

    Ok(HttpRequest {
        method,
        path,
        version,
        headers,
        has_body,
        body
    })
}
```

There's also tests for each method:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_next_req_line() {
    let req = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Length: 3\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nlel".as_bytes();

    let (mut lel, mut pos) = next_req_line(req, 0);
    assert_eq!("GET / HTTP/1.1", String::from_utf8_lossy(lel));
    assert!(lel.len() > 0);
    assert_eq!(16, pos);

    let (lel, pos) = next_req_line(req, pos);
    assert_eq!("Content-Length: 3", String::from_utf8_lossy(lel));
    assert!(lel.len() > 0);
    assert_eq!(35, pos);

    let (lel, pos) = next_req_line(req, pos);
    assert_eq!("", String::from_utf8_lossy(lel));
    assert!(lel.len() == 0);
    assert_eq!(37, pos);

    let (lel, pos) = next_req_line(req, pos);
    assert_eq!("", String::from_utf8_lossy(lel));
    assert!(lel.len() == 0);

    let (lel, pos) = next_req_line(req, pos);
    assert_eq!("", String::from_utf8_lossy(lel));
    assert!(lel.len() == 0);

    let (lel, pos) = next_req_line(req, pos);
    assert_eq!("lel", String::from_utf8_lossy(lel));
    assert!(lel.len() == 3);
}

    #[test]
    fn test_parse_request() {
        let mut request = String::from("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        request.push_str("Content-Length: 3\r\n");
        request.push_str("\r\n");
        request.push_str("lel");
        let request = request.as_bytes();

        match parse_request(&request) {
            Ok(http_request) => {
                assert_eq!(http_request.method, "GET");
                assert_eq!(http_request.path, "/");
                assert_eq!(http_request.version, "HTTP/1.1");
            },
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

The commented lines are just to show what's happening, and that's where I saw this output:

```
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.53s
     Running target/debug/deps/rweb-6bbc2a3130f7e3d9

running 4 tests
test http::testing::test_next_req_line ... ok
test http::testing::test_parse_header ... ok
test http::testing::test_parse_method_path_and_version ... ok
--- parsed method path version  ---
--- got next line: 35, Content-Length: 3 ---
LOOP
--- parsed header: Content-Length: 3 ---
--- got next line: 37,  ---
--- got next line: 39, lel ---
LOOP
--- got next line: 37,  ---
10
test http::testing::test_parse_request ... ok

test result: ok. 4 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

It seems that the `while` loop is not re-assigning the `line` and `curr_req_reader_pos` variables, but for me it made perfect sense to expect that the loop would update these variables and parse every header. However, it works perfecly outside a loop, as anyone can see in the tests.

I can't figure out why this happens with my current undertanding of Rust, why does it happen?

Comment: You aren't "reassigning" variables in the loop, you create new variables that temporarily shadow the outer ones and then go out of scope when the iteration ends.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't "reassigning" variables in the loop, you create new variables that temporarily shadow the outer ones and then go out of scope when the iteration ends.

Here's an illustration as to what is going on in simplified pseudocode:

```
let x0 = 0
{
    let x1 = x0 + 1 // original x gets shadowed, x = 1
    let x2 = x1 + 1 // x1 gets shadowed, x = 2
} // both x1 and x2 go out of scope
let x1 = x0 + 1 // x = 1
```

Comment: Yes. Get rid of the "let"s in the loop. Let will create a new variable with the same name in the inner scope. This is "shadowing", as the answer explained. To reassign, do "x = SOMETHING"